# Unable to get the value sent by the Cloud Functions for Firebase response.send method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I use React.js and axios.

`firebase emulators:start --only functions`
The emulator returns a normal value when you send a request to the URI, but if you use React to display the returned value, you will see an HTML tag.

Could you tell me how to use the values returned by Cloud Functions in React?
What have I misunderstood?

---

Here's the code

**Cloud Functions**

```js
export const resKeyword = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const keyword = req.query.keyword;
  res.send({ keyword: keyword });
});
```

**React.js**

```js
const getJSON = async (value) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get("/keyword", {
    params: { keyword: value },
  });
  console.log(data);
};
```

---

Emulator results
[Emulator results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0az6v.png)

```
{ "keyword":"test" }
```

Console.log
[Console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivW3m.jpg)

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/>
...
...
</body></html>
```

---

## Add

I created a demo based on the code I wrote in the question, and it worked without any problems(why).
So I prepared a demo that generated the same error as my production environment.

[Repository(GitHub)](https://github.com/C-V-Alkan/test)

The differences from the code in question are as follows.

- Get the URL of the GIF from [Giphy](https://developers.giphy.com/docs/api#quick-start-guide)
- Use Typescirpt

The results returned by the demo's emulator are as follows.
endpoint: `http://localhost:5001/test-a3f76/us-central1/resGifs?keyword=test`
[Emulator results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/970MO.png)

The result of the console will be the same HTML tag.
[Console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivW3m.jpg)

Comment: Can you put your code in the sandbox and share it here?

Comment: @Chetan Kumar Thank you very much for your comments. I've added it, so please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your cloud function is not returning JSON format as expected.

Try using:

```js
res.json({ keyword: keyword });
```

Instead of:

```js
res.send({ keyword: keyword });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried the json method but I couldn't find any change in the emulator and console results.